# How does Outlook.com have the title text underlined?

Tags: html, css, title, outlook.com

In the source code, Outlook.com has this:

```
<title>Outlook.com - [my email address]</title>
```

However, when the page is run in a browser it displays with the title underlined in a browser tab:
[image]

I am running Firefox 33.0 on Windows XP, however this persists on Firefox 33.0.2 on Windows 7.

How is this possible? There doesn't seem to be any CSS rules defined for the title tag. Is it even possible to style the title tag?

Comment: What kind of OS and browser are you running?

Comment: @Dropout - thank you, I will clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have Webmail notifier installed? [LINK](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626115)

Comment: Yes. Thank for you for the link, now I realise what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question of is it possible to style the tag  is no.

From W3C:

> The title of a document is specified by the TITLE element. The TITLE
>   element should occur in the HEAD of the document.
>
> There may only be one title in any document. It should identify the
>   content of the document in a fairly wide context.
>
> The title is not part of the text of the document, but is a property
>   of the whole document. It may not contain anchors, paragraph marks, or
>   highlighting. The title may be used to identify the node in a history
>   list, to label the window displaying the node, etc. It is not normally
>   displayed in the text of a document itself. Contrast titles with
>   headings . The title should ideally be less than 64 characters in
>   length. That is, many applications will display document titles in
>   window titles, menus, etc where there is only limited room. Whilst
>   there is no limit on the length of a title (as it may be automatically
>   generated from other data), information providers are warned that it
>   may be truncated if long.

[Read More](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html)

The browser however could style it tho I'm not sure why they would. I cannot replicate this as I'm using a mac and have a Windows 8 VM, but I would guess the browser handles some URL's differently.

Comment: So how does outlook.com create underlines text in the title tag?

Comment: @MathiasFoster I did say in my answer that the browser (firefox) must be doing it. Its a UI design choice, run some tests and see what other websites do it and then find what they all have in common. Could be as simple as secure websites have it.

Comment: It does appear to be only Firefox that does this - I have just tested in Chrome.

Comment: @MathiasFoster I want to find out exactly what it is now so I'm going to create a VM with Win 7 and have a mess around. I will comment back here if I find anything more.

Comment: You may be interested in Anfuca's answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/26648228/3530667

Comment: @MathiasFoster Ah there we go! Didn't even have time to test it yet. Well that saved me time, good stuff.